# Jquery code to replace the content of a <li> with a master value following some conditions

Tags: jquery

I am pretty sure my logic is flowed, so please help:

I have a classic unordered list, where some **li** values are different ("Hello 1", "Hello 2", "Hello 3") and some **li** values are the same (the "Hello World" ones).

I also have a MATCH VALUE which is "Hello World" from the data-ANCHOR.

```
 <ul class="traffic" data-ANCHOR="Hello World">
       <li>Hello 1</li>
       <li>Hello 2</li>
       <li>Hello 3</li>
       <li>Hello World</li>
       <li>Hello World</li>
  </ul>
```

I tried to make a Jquery code that checks every **li** If the content of the **li** is the same with my MATCH VALUE (from the data-ANCHOR), write something else instead.

```
var ANCHOR = $("ul.traffic").data('ANCHOR');
var ANCHORMATCH = $("ul.traffic li a").text();

if(ANCHOR == ANCHORMATCH){
    $('ul.traffic li a').replaceWith('hey hey');
}
```

**It does not work, nothing happens.**

But if I change the if condition to `if(ANCHOR != ANCHORMATCH)` - the code replaces all the `<li>`'s contents with "hey hey".

I am a newb but my gut tells me I should use a loop or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ANCHOR = $("ul.traffic").data('ANCHOR');
var ANCHORMATCH = $("ul.traffic li a").text();

if(ANCHOR == ANCHORMATCH){
    $('ul.traffic li a').replaceWith('hey hey');
}
```

This code only ever looks at the content of the *first* `ul.traffic li a` element. You need to use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) to loop over each of them. (In fact, your HTML doesn't even have `a` elements: I've modified the code accordingly.)

```
var ANCHOR = $("ul.traffic").data('anchor');

$('ul.traffic li').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.text() === ANCHOR) {
        $this.html('hey hey');
    }
});
```

Note also that jQuery will always move `data-ANCHOR` to be `data('anchor')`. It's probably wise to give the attribute the normal casing (`data-anchor`).

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5jkk/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this

```
$(".traffic li").each(function(i){

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul.traffic li:contains("' + $("ul.traffic").data('ANCHOR') + '")').html('hey hey');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember jQuery / JavaScript normalizes all data items to lowercase.

```
var ANCHOR = $("ul.traffic").data('ANCHOR');
```

should be

```
var ANCHOR = $("ul.traffic").data('anchor');
```

Here is a working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5hAna/

```
var ANCHOR = $("ul.traffic").data('anchor');

$('ul.traffic li').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === ANCHOR) {
        $(this).html('hey hey');
    }
});
```